# How to store and retrieve Date from sqlite db in Android?

Tags: java, android, datetime

I'm storing date in sqlite database in Android as this:

```
initialValues.put(KEY_TIME, time.getTime());
```

where time is an instance of Date (which has the correct time) and KEY_TIME is an integer column.

Once stored, when I retrieve it with a query such as this:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " order  by date(" + KEY_TIME + ") DESC" ;
```

I never get the data with the recent one first.

I get spurious time which is almost 40 years old. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: sqlite date and Java Date aren't the same thing. You're storing a date-field in who-knows-what-format and then evaluating it in SQL is an ISO8601 time-string. Store the timestamp as a string, ISO8601 preferred, but anything sortable (yyyymmdd) will do.

Comment: Considering my format is more of yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z' How do I achieve this?

Comment: Just do `ORDER BY " + KEY_TIME` and forget the date. Your format looks ISO8601, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`java.util.Date.getTime()` returns the number of milliseconds since the start of 1970 (epoch time). SQLite can deal with Unix epoch time, which is the same value, but expressed in seconds (see [`java.util.Date.getTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime%28%29)).

The mismatch of seconds and milliseconds is the reason you are seeing incorrect dates.

You can divide the value by 1000 to get Unix style epoch time, and specify 'unixepoch' (see [SQLite Time & Date Functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)) to SQLite's date function, e.g.:

```
SELECT date(KEY_TIME / 1000, 'unixepoch') FROM TABLE_NAME
```

If you are using a `java.sql.Date` it is the same (that class extends `java.util.Date`).

However, as 323go mentioned in the question comments, just sort directly by `KEY_TIME`, which will give you the sort order you are looking for.